# Plot graph // Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-graphview

I try to plot a graph with data from Firebase. Before this error Its show y-axis(with x-axis that created by my own). But when I try to plot x-axis with data from firebase ( which in firebase is type String)this error happen.

```
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:425)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:216)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:178)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:603)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:562)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:432)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:231)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:203)
    at com.example.smartbin.GraphActivity$1.onDataChange(GraphActivity.java:62)
```

Here is my code that seem to be problem

```
database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference = database.getReference("test").orderByChild("DevEUI_uplink/DevAddr").equalTo("AB000001");

    }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataPoint[] dp=new DataPoint[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
            int index=0;

            for (DataSnapshot myDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                PointValue pointValue = myDataSnapshot.child("DevEUI_uplink/payload_parsed/frames/1").getValue(PointValue.class);
                PointValue pointValue2 = myDataSnapshot.child("DevEUI_uplink").getValue(PointValue.class); //GraphActivity.java:62
                dp[index]= new DataPoint(pointValue2.getFCntUp(),pointValue.getyValue());
                index++;
            }
```

And this is my code from PointValue.class I also try to convert Data from String to Integer but not sure if I'm doing it right.

```
public void setValue(int value)
{
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue()
{
    return value;
}
public void setFCntUp(String FCntUp){
    this.FCntUp = FCntUp;
}
public int getFCntUp(){
    return Integer.parseInt(FCntUp);
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I already fix it. it's work now thank you for trying to help. I don't know the rules here. Do I have to post the solutions?

Comment: Sure, if you found the working solution, you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted Integer.parseint in PointValue.class and just get String. I get String from PointValue.class and turn to Int in my MainActivity.

```
            for (DataSnapshot myDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                PointValue pointValue = myDataSnapshot.child("DevEUI_uplink/payload_parsed/frames/1").getValue(PointValue.class);
                PointValue pointValue2 = myDataSnapshot.child("DevEUI_uplink").getValue(PointValue.class);
                nvalue = pointValue2.getFCntUp();
                x = Integer.parseInt(nvalue);
                y = pointValue.getValue();

                dp[index]= new DataPoint(x,y);
                index++;
            }
            series.resetData(dp);
        }`
```

Here is my PointValue.class

```
 public void setFCntUp(String FCntUp)
{
    this.FCntUp = FCntUp;
}
public String getFCntUp()
{
    return FCntUp;
}


public void setValue(int value)
{
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue()
{
    return value;
}
```

Not sure if It's a solution for problem but it's work for me.